# How to open tab on mouse over using jquery without using iframe and putting all content in same page?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, accessibility

I just want to open another tab without refreshing and on mouse over like this http://fnagel.github.com/jQuery-Accessible-RIA/Tabs/mouseover.html . Is it possible with these things.

- Pages url should be change like as it
  now. I want to keep content in separate page
- on clicking on another tab it should
  open without refreshing
- i don't want to open tab content as a
  iframe

I liked the idea of this http://jonplante.com/demo/tabs-1-2/?js=on but page url is not changing so other pages cannot be bookmarked

Comment: There isn't a good way to change the URL and still load content using Ajax. Some sites change the # part, but this ends up (at best) with multiple URIs to the content — one which only works for JS users. As a rule of thumb - if the content is worth bookmarking, it is worth having a proper page and loading it using normal linking.

Comment: @David Dorward - ok so there is no way. then should i delete this question

Comment: @David Dorward - is it can be possible like this http://expressionengine.com/ see site map with js off and on.

Comment: That is a different use case to the one you described.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery Tools Tabs handles the back button as is shown in this demo:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/history.html

Comment: Link in answer dead - 404 Not Found | Apologies! | We couldn't find what you're looking for..

Answer (score 1):

Surey, and it's easy.  First, your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab" id="tab-1">Tab 1</div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab-2">Tab 2</div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab-3">Tab 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent">
    <div class="content visible" id="content-tab-1"><!-- content for Tab 1 --></div>
    <div class="content hidden" id="content-tab-2"><!-- content for Tab 2 --></div>
    <div class="content hidden" id="content-tab-3"><!-- content for Tab 3 --></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example assumes you have the classes `hidden` and `visible` set up to hide and show an element.  The `tab` and `content` classes are for use with JS and styling, and the other classes are really only for styling purposes.  Now for the JS:

```
$( function ( ) {
  $('.tabs .tab').mouseover( function( ) {
    $('.tabContent .content').addClass( 'hidden' ).removeClass( 'visible' );
    $('#' + $(this).attr( 'id' )).removeClass( 'hidden' ).addClass( 'visible' );
  } );
} );
```

There might be a small error or two in that JS as I just wrote it here for you, but the concept will work.  You just have to get your styling right.  I would set `position: relative;` on `div.tabContent` and `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;` on `div.tabContent div.content`.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a jQueryUI. It provides 'tabs' functionality:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

It has demos online, and if you look at the right-hand menu, you'll see that AJAX and mouse-over are demos 2 and 3.

Comment: Do you want the URLs to be bookmarkable, or is it something else? 

You can only change the # portion of the URL without navigating away, so if you want AJAX loading, you'll have to use a # argument.

This should work with the UI tabs scheme by default - the only reason you can't see it in the demo is that the right side-menu already manipulates the # portion of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add a hash name to the document.location (I'm not including the tab-code itself, for readability)

Let's say your tab HTML is like:

```
<a href="/page-to-fetch">Page</a>
```

Then Your javascript would be like this:

```
$('a.tab').mouseover(function(){
    document.location = document.location.hash = this.href;
    // Insert code for loading ajax content of the url of the tab pressed
    // Something like
    $('.tab-content-area').load(this.href);
});
```

That way, when you click a tab, the URL will change to whatever it is + '#sjjdsjsd' - so the URL changes. And your back button will work as well.

Then you just need to add code for when the page loads, to check if there's a hash value set, and load that content (if we're coming from another page or something like that)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.location.hash) {
        $('.tab-content-area').load(document.location.hash);
        // Or however you're doing it or want to do it.
    }
});
```

That should be about all you need. But I don't know your tab code or if you're using a tab-plugin.